Embarcadero Delphi DCC64 for Modern x64 build?
Is there a new DCC64 for the Modern x64 build (needed for linking with C++Builder using Modern x64)?  Or is there some new parameter to use with DCC64?
TIA!!

Related/dupe: "Windows 64-bit" vs "Windows 64-bit (Modern)" in Delphi IDE Library Paths

The "Modern" toolchain only applies to C++ not Delphi, so there is no new Delphi compiler executable for "Modern".
However, if you want to compile a Delphi package so it can be used with the "Modern" C++ toolchain, you do need to add "Modern" to the package's target platforms.
That said, you really shouldn't be invoking the command-line compilers directly.  Delphi (and C++Builder/RAD Studio) has been using MSBuild since 2007. You just tell it the project and platforms to compile and let it work out the parameters needed for the individual compilers.  Refer to Embarcadero's documentation for more details:
Building a Project Using an MSBuild Command

compiling something old ... looks like undocumented (from what I can find) -JF:COFFI and "set PLATFORM=Win64x" seem to work with dcc64.
